# I cannot find 'Record Robo Script' in android studio 3.0

Tags: android-studio, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I want to use Robo test from google firebase for my application.
My application needs login process, so I want to use Robo script to automate login process.

However, I cannot find a menu "Record Robo Script and use it to Guide Robo Test" at Android Studio 3.0.

This menu is suggested at below document.

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/robo-ux-test#scripting

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions in each step as documented?  Including selecting Tools > Firebase from the menu bar to bring up the Firebase Assistant?

Comment: @DougStevenson, sure it is. I attached screenshot below

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this at Android Studio 3.0
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The menu item is visible in Android Studio 3.1, so may have just been an incompatibility with Android Studio 3.0.